# Animate view in relative layout to align parent top

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout (let's call it A), inside a scroll view, inside a relative layout (we will call this layout B)

What I'm trying to do is remove a child from A, insert it into B and align it to the parent top (right below the action bar).

I've been trying to animate this slide up, and back down to it's original position without any luck.

Any idea how can I perform this animation?

Answer (score 1):

A very late reply, but here's how I managed this:

**center_to_top_center.xml** (located in res/anim/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:fromYDelta="00%p"
        android:toXDelta="00%p"
        android:toYDelta="-40%p" />
</set>
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.imageView2)
    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home, false);
        beginLogoAnimation();
    }


    private void beginLogoAnimation(){
        Animation translateAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.center_to_top_center);
        translateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
        translateAnim.setFillBefore(false);
        translateAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        mImageView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
    }
}
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are Animating Layout Changes 
Try adding this to your layout block:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#layout